# 64 Bit Excel 2016 VBA - No more DisplayAlerts?

Tags: vba, excel

I am teaching VBA lessons in Germany and Switzerland. One of the companies that I work for has recently switched to 64 Bit Office.

Before that - and still on my PC, which runs 32 Bit Office - when you delete a sheet you will be prompted by an alert. In the latest two trainings I gave for the company, this was no longer necessary. The sheet, whether or not it contained any data, was quietly deleted.

My question is: Did Microsoft change something about this? Is it a bug? Will it be repaired to work as before?

Does somebody have any idea on this?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Joern.

Comment: 64 bit windows for me at least in 2016 prompts before delete 16.0.4549.1000 Office Prof Plus 2016

Comment: Was `Application.DisplayAlerts` turned off?

Comment: Beg your pardon, but what's the connection between DisplayAlerts and Office's bitness? Better show us your instead of vague questions.

Comment: @JohnyL Well, it has happened in the past that the x64 version of a product has a bug that the x86 version does not have.

Comment: Well, Office 2016, really, has some bugs (I remembered one bug found by mrexcel.com's moderator), but can't confirm that `DisplayAlerts` has some other behavior. Although, I use only Excel 2010 :)

Comment: Answering your comments:
No, DisplayAlerts was not turned off. It does not show any difference between being turned on or off.
And yes: The Bit-Version does obviously make a difference..